# Android Theme AppCompat how to style menu item selector

Tags: android, android-actionbar, android-optionsmenu

I have used `Android Support V7`'s  `@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light` for my styles. And to be more specific I have used [Actionbar Style Generator](http://jgilfelt.github.io/android-actionbarstylegenerator/.)

I  want my overall theme to be in light red. So,for `options menu item` selector,I need light red color to work. I have made `Accent color` in `Actionbar Style Generator` to red as well. But the `options menu item` is always `default blue`. I have changed following as well to be sure

```
<item name="popupMenuStyle">@style/PopupMenu.Fsa</item>
<item name="dropDownListViewStyle">@style/DropDownListView.Fsa</item>

<style name="DropDownListView.Fsa" parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Light.ListView.DropDown">
    <item name="android:listSelector">@drawable/red_selector</item>
</style>
```

But also,the `options menu item` selector is always `default blue`. I have browsed several tutorials on `Actionbar styling` and they were also of no help. So any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your hardware needs Android Support or not, your XML must contain both item style reference:

```
 <!-- Support library compatibility -->
 <item name="popupMenuStyle">@style/PopupMenu.Fsa</item>
 <item name="dropDownListViewStyle">@style/DropDownListView.Fsa</item>
```

and

```
 <!-- Support library not needed -->
 <item name="android:popupMenuStyle">@style/PopupMenu.Fsa</item>
 <item name="android:dropDownListViewStyle">@style/DropDownListView.Fsa</item>
```

regardless the fact of Android Studio show error for "requires API level XX", it compiles as well and now the correct styles are applicable in both hardware, who needs and not the support library.